# Math.Pow is not calculating correctly

Tags: c#, pow

I'm having a problem with C#. To be precise with the Math.pow(). If I try to calculate 15^14 then I get "29192926025390624". But if I calculate it with Wolfram Alpha I get "29192926025390625". As you can see this only difference is 1 number. Wolfram Alpha is correct though. Why isn't C# ? and how do I fix this so I can get the correct value in C# ?7

My code is fairly simple since I'm just trying with hardcoded examples. So what I'm doing is : `Math.Pow(15,14);` This gives `29192926025390624`. And not "29192926025390625" which is the correct answer.

Links : [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=15%5E14)

Comment: Without seeing your code, anything will be a guess. My guess is that Wolfram Alpha is calculating it using a higher precision floating point type.

Comment: By the way, assuming that 29192926025390625 is correct (it looks correct: it ends with a "5"), then `Math.Pow` behaves according to spec: 29192926025390624 **is** the nearest double-precision IEEE 754 number. The other nearby double-precision number is 29192926025390628.

Comment: It is computing correctly; it is your understand of floating-point arithmetic and the specification for `Math.Pow` that is flawed. Enjoy: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Math.Pow` operates on floating-point types, which are *by definition* inaccurate. If you need arbitrary precision integers, use an arbitrary precision integer type such as the [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) structure. BigInteger also has a [Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.pow.aspx) method.

Comment: The BigInteger.pow() did the trick (ModPow even). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ojtwist: Just a warning... if performance really matters for you, and that operation on BigInteger is repeated a really big number of times, you should think to change strategy (e.g. build your own Pow function for longs for example, as suggested in Yuriy Faktorovich's answer).

Answer (score 5):

[Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) works on doubles. This implementation with long gets the correct answer:

```
Func<long, int, long> power = null;
power = (i, p) => p == 1 ? i : i*power(i, p - 1);
Console.WriteLine(power(15, 14));
```

Comment: be carefull with < 1 powers (looks like a stackoverflow to me :p) (handle the 0 case should be enought since with deal with ints)

Answer (score 4):

[Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) works on doubles. [Doubles are 64 bit floating point and have about 15-16 digits of precision in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx), and therefore, what you are seeing is a rounding error. That is how floating point numbers work.

If you need more precision, try to use [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx). It is 128 bits and uses 10 as the base. This gives you accurate representation of numbers up to 28-29 significant digits. You can easily define your own Pow method for decimal.

If `decimal` is not enough, turn to [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx), which was added in .NET 4.

Comment: `decimal`'s are floating-point as well, they just use base 10 instead of 2 --> http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx

Answer (score 1):

C#'s Math.pow returns a Double, an IEEE 754 standard floating point number.  It only has 15 significant digits:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Math.Pow() is working correctly its problem with double data type
  **see this.**

```
        double i = 29192926025390625;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}",i);//the result will be 29192926025390624.0
```

Oops Sorry, Check value by breakpoint; in your program;