# What's difference between Math.pow(9, 18) and 9^18

Tags: java, floating-accuracy, pow

when I use `Math.pow(9, 18) =150094635296999136`

when I use web Calculator 9^18 = 150094635296999121  (http://web2.0calc.com/)

when I use Google calculator 9^18 = 1.50094635 × 10^17

why it is different ?

Comment: different because of precision.

Comment: web2.0calc.com and google calculator are showing same  results but, in different notation. Google is displaying in **scientific** notation. Some precision is lost in scientific notation.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407298/am-i-going-crazy-on-is-math-pow-broken

Answer (score 16):

At that range, the difference between successive `double` values is 32. 150094635296999121 is the correct answer as an integer, but that number cannot be exactly represented as a `double`.

You can use [`BigInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to get the exact answer:

```
Math.pow(9, 18) == 150094635296999136
BigInteger.valueOf(9).pow(18) == 150094635296999121
```