# math.sqrt returns 0

Tags: c#, function, return, math.sqrt

I have a c# function that contains formula to calculate euclidean distance of some points. I got the point's position defined by R(rx,ry) and L(lx,ly).

at first, I tried to write the code like this:

```
double dRightLeft = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(rx - lx, 2) + Math.Pow(ry - ly, 2)));
```

it returns 0.0.

then I tried to split the variable to check where did I do wrong, like this:

```
 double rl = (Math.Pow(rx - lx, 2) + Math.Pow(ry - ly, 2));
 double dRightLeft = Math.Sqrt(rl);
```

the rl variable returns a valid value of its operation. but then when I tried to get the square root out of it, the dRighLeft variable still returns 0.0.
I tried both assigned and unassigned dRightLeft like this:

```
//assigned
dRightLeft = 0;
//unassigned
dRightLeft;
```

they both still returns 0.0 value.

here's my short but complete program where I get the rx, ry, lx, and ly value:

```
public Bitmap getDetectedImage()
{
int rx, rx, lx, ly, ...;
double dRightLeft = 0;
...
//righteyeloop
for (int x = fo.rightEye.X; x < (fo.rightEye.X + fo.rightEye.Width); x++)
{
    for (int y = fo.rightEye.Y; y < (fo.rightEye.Y + fo.rightEye.Height); y++)
    {    //segmentation...//   
         rPixel++;
         result.byteImage[x, y].R = 0;
         result.byteImage[x, y].G = 255;
         result.byteImage[x, y].B = 0;
//to get the the first pixel detected//
         if (rPixel == 1)
         {
             result.byteImage[x, y].R = 255;
             result.byteImage[x, y].G = 0;
             result.byteImage[x, y].B = 0;

rx = x + (fo.rightEye.Width / setting.featureWidth * setting.eyeHeight / setting.eyeWidth);
ry = y + (fo.rightEye.Height / setting.featureWidth * setting.eyeHeight / setting.eyeWidth);
         }
    }
}
//lefteyeloop basically the same type as righteyeloop//
.....
//this to count the distance of righteye and lefteye
    double rl = ((rx - lx) * (rx - lx) + (ry - ly) * (ry - ly));
    double dRightLeft = Math.Pow(rl, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Do `r` and `l` represent the same point by any chance?

Comment: what are the values of ry, ly, rx and lx?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What's the `valid value of its operation` that you tested?

Comment: Seems that `rx == lx` and `ry == ly`. Just check values in debugger

Comment: How do you ensure that it is zero?

Comment: this is my example:
R(212,179) and L(291,180)
the value of rl = 6242.0

Comment: @rfa What are the values and types of `ry`, `ly`, `rx` and `lx`?

Comment: Something else you're not showing is happening: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2SDnXc

Comment: the types of ry, ly, rx, and lx are int.

Comment: @rfa and the values? Are they all zero perhaps?

Comment: rx = 212, ry = 179, lx = 291, ly = 180

Comment: @rfa Using those values, the output is `79.0063288604147`, there is something else you are not showing us. Can you show us the entire method?

Comment: That is not a complete program, I can not copy and paste it and run it on my machine. Go to https://dotnetfiddle.net/, write the absolute smallest program that runs on that site and demonstrates the problem (Bitmap is not needed to demonstrate your problem, just write a function that only includes the math portion and outputs the numbers) then copy the code in to your question and maybe even include a link to the runnable dotnetfiddle program.

Comment: solved. the blame is on me. I should put a getter variable right below them to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that Math.Pow deals with doubles, which have low precision [(see this SO question for more discussion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297454/math-pow-is-not-calculating-correctly). The immediate instinct is to just replace Math.Pow by writing out the multiplication:

```
double rl = ((rx - lx) * (rx - lx) + (ry - ly) * (ry - ly));
double dRightLeft = Math.Sqrt(rl);
```

From the [Math.Pow reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx), it seems that, with an exponent of two, the only way to return 0 is if your base (i.e. `rx - lx` or `ry - ly`) is also 0.

Comment: is integer divsion to blame? in C# (and many other languages), writing 3/5 returns 0. it seems unlikely, especially given the values you provided

Comment: but I got the valid rl value.
rx = 212, ry = 179, lx = 291, ly = 180.

Comment: I think it's best to post the entire method/class where you are having the issue, since, at this point, we've determined that Math.Sqrt() and Math.Pow() are not causing the problem.